# "Consider using `transfer` in place of 'call.value()`" is a false error message by ethlint

Tags: error

I am getting following message when I use `solium` or `ethlint`, which is actually not correct and confusing developers. I have opened a [issue related to that](https://github.com/duaraghav8/Ethlint/issues/280):

Solium returns **error** for using `call.value()`.

```
error: Consider using `transfer` in place of `call.value()`. security/no-call-value
```

---

**!!!** As for the solidity version 0.6.0, it is recommended to use `call.value()` from now on and using `transfer` is not recommended. **!!!**

---

Please see [Stop Using Solidity’s transfer() Now](https://diligence.consensys.net/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/), its [medium link](https://medium.com/consensys-diligence/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now-b1b6d2d00faf).

=> I just want to bring this issue up since `ethlint` is misguiding the developers and verify by asking that should we stick by using `transfer` or `call.value`?

Comment: Your link gives 404

Comment: updated @LauriPeltonen

Comment: There is a conflict on the information for `transfer||call.value()` usage // I didn't get any response from `ethlint` developers and I want to be sure should I stick by using `transfer` or `call.value`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of opinions, at the moment. The 2300 gas stipend is still considered a good reentrancy guard, but it is not. Particularly in the mid term.

In my opinion you should use the call() and have the control of your own call, deciding all the particularities of the thing.

It is not related to solc 0.5.x or 0.6.x: it is the correction of a clear error: you should manage your code, not playing with double spending or reentrancy hoping that the current limits of your environment shall save you forever.

In my opinion the warning message will be fixed later, but the concept is clear to all just now.

Comment: Its not a `warning` message, its a `error` message for using `call.value()` by the ethlint (solium) , which is misguiding.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said: it is a warning. If, at the moment, it is treated as an error, it is a bug.